# Convert a Pandas dataframe cell to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has the below columns

```
Record Type     Value
100             1,2,3,4,5
200             0,10
300             1
```

Expected results:
`list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your 'Value' values are of string data type, so this code just maps the string value to a list of ints.

`list1 = list(map(int, df['Value'][0].split(",")))`

Comment: Thank you. works perfect. can we get the list based on the condition "Record type". For example - record type 100 should return [1,2,3,4,5] for record type 200 it should return [0,10] ?

Comment: @rmutalik @ What if the entire column needs to be converted to list? Like - 

Record Type     Value
100             [1,2,3,4,5]
200             [0,10]
300             [1]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Record Type': ['100', '200', '300'],
           'Value': [(1,2,3,4,5), (0,10), 1]})

def returnlist(df):
    v = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
             if type(df['Value'][i]) != int:
             x = list(df['Value'][i])
             v.append(x)           
    return v
```

Comment: Thanks! This function helped me to convert mixed column values (some strings, some lists) to all list values. Other methods split strings into words or characters but I needed to preserve multi-word strings.

Answer (score -1):

[df.values.tolist()](https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/) is what you are looking :)

Comment: That will convert the entire dataframe into lists which is not what i would want. I only require the value of record type 100 (1,2,3,4,5) to be converted to list and not the others.